# Pass arguments to an action in dictionary at initialization C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates, arguments, action

I have a `Dictionary` which has `KeyCode` as a key and an `Action<int>` as value,h however I want to give the `Action` parameters at the initialization of the dictionary like this :

```
    someDictionary = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Action<int>>()
    {
        {KeyCode.Alpha1, GoToCameraPosition(0) },
    };
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Note that the second type parameter to `Dictionary` has changed from your original: The action you create has no parameters, because the parameter for the action it calls is built into the anonymous lambda stored in the dictionary.

```
someDictionary = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Action>()
{
    {KeyCode.Alpha1, () => GoToCameraPosition(0) },
};
```

Call like so:

```
KeyCode key = KeyCode.Alpha1;
Action act = null;

if (someDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out act))
{
    //  act is a method that calls GoToCameraPosition(0)
    act();
}
```

Or

```
foreach (var kvp in someDictionary)
{
    kvp.Value();
}
```

Or, if you're certain it's in there...

```
someDictionary[KeyCode.Alpha1]();
```

Comment: if you are using C#6 there is a (imo) much prettier initializer for dictionaries

Comment: one question cant I just do `Value.Invoke()` ?

Comment: @GeekCodingMaster Do you mean if you're looping through the KeyValuePairs in the dictionary? Yes, but you don't need `Invoke()`. `someDictionary.Values.First()();` works, or `foreach (var kvp in someDictionary) kvp.Value();` I mean, you *can* use `Invoke()`, if you want to. But there's no need.